# XNA 4.0 Adding surrounding Sphere/Box to the terrain

Tags: c#, xna

i have been searching for long in order to find how i can place a sphere/cube around my playfield so ill have an effect similar to sky. I have seen SkySpheres/Boxes but couldnt implement them . Im looking for a rather simple solution since my play field is really small and i just need something to replace the Clear(Color.Black) .I dont care about collision i just need it to be there with a texture on . Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at Riemers XNA Tutorial

[HERE](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Skybox.php) is the post on the skybox.

Comment: I have already tried that but my camera wont work with it . I was thinking about it and what it would be most suitable would be  having a cylinder with a texture inside . Do i need a special model to do that or is there a command that will draw the inside of the model ?Im not really expirienced so some code/ tutorial for the draw will help. thanks

Comment: @latusaki: What you are asking about are culling modes. You can set CullCounterClockwiseFace in the RenderState to have the interior of models rendered, and render your skybox cylinder/cube/sphere in a separate Spritebatch. After that, reset RenderState, create a new SpriteBatch and render your world. By the way, skyboxes should be more efficient if done with cubes.

Comment: @latusaki, why would a cylinder work if the box does not work with your camera. In essence both are a model drawn so that the camera is always at the center and the model tracks with the movement of the camera.

Comment: Finally added a skybox. I had seen that tutorial before but didn't realise i had to use the effects file.Thanks tho.